# Display another div when someone hover over a div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 separate div tags. I want div2 to appear when someone hovers over div1.
This is what I am trying to achieve.. [image]

### HTML

```
    <div class="div1">
       HOVER TO ADD DETAILS
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <input type="image" src="img1.png" name="btn1" value="btn1">
        <input type="image" src="img2.png" name="btn1" value="btn1">
        <input type="image" src="img3.png" name="btn1" value="btn1">
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
    .div1{ background-color:#bcbcbc; width: 400px; height:45px;}
    .div2{ display:none; position:relative; width: 50px; margin:0 auto;}
    .div1 > .div2 {display:block; }
```

This is what I am trying.. It is not working. I am not able to show div2 when I hover div1. I've searched over the net but not able to find what I want. any idea how to do this. I would appreciate a css way of doing it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `z-index` of `div-1` on hover?

Comment: I havent tried z-index because div2 doesn't show up.. It goes back or comes over is a separate issue..

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/PKGT6/)

Comment: yea i want the same effect.. but why is this flickering??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Probably because when you hover over div1, its  z-index is reduced and div2 comes up. So now you're hovering over div2 instead

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/PKGT6/1/) doesn't have the flickering issue. But I'm assuming you want to click on the div2 images after hover, and I don't think this would work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make .div1 the child of .div2 like:

```
<div class='div1'><div class='div2'>...</div></div>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.div2 {
    display: none;
}

.div1:hover > .div2 {
    display: block;
}

.div2:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

And also add your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 .div1:hover + .div2 {display:block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.div2 {
    display: none;
}

.div1:hover ~ .div2 {
    display: block;
}

.div2:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Also it is better to use IDs like #div1 and #div2 as classes are to specify a style for more than one elements.

Comment: That is a descendant selector, .div1 and .div2 are siblings. `.div1:hover + .div2` or `.div1:hover ~.div2` would work.

Comment: I tried that to.. but did it with class..   .div1:hover  .div2 {display:block ;}   nothing happened..

Comment: You'l also have to add `.div2:hover { display:block}` since once the .div2 appears you will no longer hover over .div1

Comment: I have tried all the methods  but I dont know what the problem is.. I still cant get div2 to appear on hover..

Comment: I got it correct.. I made Div2 the child of div1  `<div class="div1">... <div class="div2"> ... </div> </div>`  and i used `div1:hover > div2 {display:block;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
.div1 {
 background-color:#bcbcbc;
 width: 400px;
 height:45px;
}
.div2 {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 width: 50px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.div1:hover~.div2{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(it fixes the flickering issue and you can interact with the second div as well):

```
.div1 {
    z-index:1;
}
.div1:hover {
    z-index:0;
}
.div2 {
    z-index: 0;
}
.div2:hover {
    z-index:1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/PKGT6/3/)

(this basically switches the z-indices of the two divs when you hover over `.div1`)

Answer (score 0):

You should get the effect by using `~` like so:

```
.div1:hover ~ .div2 { display: block; }
```

Comment: yes I was able to get it working with ~, but it starts to flicker on- off, when I move the mouse.. any solution for that..

Comment: It actually flicker when mouse go to div2.. when mouse is on div1 it stays there fine.