# Fire click events on div but pass through hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that is absolutely positioned above other absolutely positioned divs and I want the divs below the have both mouseover, mouseout and click events and the top div to have click events also.

The only way I've been able to get mouse events on the divs below is to add pointer-events: none to the above div but then the above div does not get click events when that css property is present.

Here is a codepen showing the problem

http://codepen.io/Wryte/pen/qsEBp

Comment: And how would you click the top div and the bottom div at the same time? What you're asking for is something that would in 99% of the time mean your entire concept is flawed and needs rethinking.

Comment: Well, they are on top of each other, so clicking on one would click both. The real problem is that hover events don't go through the top one. Also the top one is semi transparent, so having the bottom ones fire hover events is desirable

Comment: From what I see in your code, you are not stopping the event from propagating therefore you should be able to catch the click event on both. You can verify that by adding to the bottom layer div mouse event listeners and do something with them.

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato I can get the click event on both but not the hover event on both

Comment: @Wryte by hover you mean mouseenter and mouseout? If the layer underneath is the main layer/container for the other smaller divs, you get the mouseenter event the first time you enter the main area and a mouse out when you leave the area.
Try this just after declaring outer:
`outer.on('mouseenter',function(){console.log('mouse entered the outer area');});
outer.on('mouseleave',function(){console.log('mouse left the outer area');});` and check the console.

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato Yes, but if I want to get mouseenter and mouseleave events on the inners (the orange rectangles) and also clicks on the shade I am currently unable to do that

Comment: Have you tried reducing the z-index of the top div on hover? So that the bottom div effectively comes up and you can hover over it too? This could be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465386/display-another-div-when-someone-hover-over-a-div/20465853#20465853

Answer (score 0):

@Wryte AH! ok, there is a problem with what you are trying to accomplish. The shade is not a container as a layer over the whole outer div that covers the rest of the inner DIVs. Since the shade div is not in the chain for event bubbling it won't get called or if you catch events on the shade DIV you won't get the events triggered on the inner DIVs.
What you can do, is to darken the outer DIV and add transparency to the inner DIVs. Why do you need to track events on the shade DIV by the way?

Comment: If this were the shade for a modal popup I would want clicks to close the modal and hide the shade but also have the hover events fire on elements below the shade before the shade is clicked

Comment: Very interesting. I recommend you to handle the shade from the click events on whatever is on top of it (the way you are explaining) and let the mouse events tickle the DIVs behind then ;). You can make a function hideShowShade and call it whenever you want.